# BI publisher returns blank report in oracle apex after deploying in tomcat

Tags: oracle-apex

please i have deployed BI 10 G, and configured everything.. i can print with the bi publisher as the print server and selecting a generic layout; but the printout returns blank when i choose to use an rich text format layout﻿ in oracle apex. 
any help

Answer (score 0):

Do you still face this issue? Please check whether the Report Layout is selected properly in the specific Report Query.